# add sum of values to first array for each matching ID in the second array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays like this:

**Array1**

```
$array1 = Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            'ID' => 101,
            'Code' => 1075,
            'Date' => '2012-03-03 17:13:12.433'
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            'ID' => 103,
            'Code' => 175,
            'Date' => '2012-09-05 20:30:02.217'
        ),

    2 => Array
        (
            'ID' => 109,
            'Code' => 178,
            'Date' => '2012-07-05 20:30:02.217'
        )

);
```

**Array2**

```
$array2 = Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            'Amount' => 1234,
            'ID' => 101
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            'Amount' => 5656,
            'ID' => 101
        ),
    2 => Array
        (
            'Amount' => 1342,
            'ID' => 103
        ),

    3 => Array
        (
            'Amount' => 0,
            'ID' => 0
        )

);
```

I'm using the code below to perform a join on the two arrays :

```
    $arr2 = array_column($array2, "ID");

    $finalArray = array();
    foreach($array1 as $arr){
        $key = array_search($arr['ID'], $arr2);
        if($key ===false){
            $key = array_search(0, $arr2);
           $array2[$key]['Found'] = "No";

        }
  else {
    $array2[$key]['Found'] = "Yes";
   }
        unset($array2[$key]['ID']);
        $finalArray[] =     array_merge($arr,$array2[$key]);
    }

    print_r($finalArray);
```

The current output using the code above is :

**finalArray**

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 101
            [Code] => 1075
            [Date] => 2012-03-03 17:13:12.433
            [Amount] => 1234 //considers only the first entry of ID 101 in array2
            [Found] => Yes
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 103
            [Code] => 175
            [Date] => 2012-09-05 20:30:02.217
            [Amount] => 1342
            [Found] => Yes
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 109
            [Code] => 178
            [Date] => 2012-07-05 20:30:02.217
            [Amount] => 0
            [Found] => No
        )

)
```

But since in **array2** there are **two entries for ID 101 but the code above only takes the first match for a matching ID**.

The expected output is :

**Desired Output**

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 101
            [Code] => 1075
            [Date] => 2012-03-03 17:13:12.433
            [Amount] => 6890 //sum of all the amounts(1234+5656)for matching ID 101
            [Found] => Yes
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 103
            [Code] => 175
            [Date] => 2012-09-05 20:30:02.217
            [Amount] => 1342
            [Found] => Yes
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 109
            [Code] => 178
            [Date] => 2012-07-05 20:30:02.217
            [Amount] => 0
            [Found] => No
        )

)
```

I'm not able to figure out how to do the addition here.

The code should do addition of the Amount feild for each matching ID of array2 and merge that amount to array1 Amount feild as shown in the expected output above.

How do I modify my current code such that it gives me the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
$finalArray = array();
foreach ($array1 as $arr1)
{
    $amount = 0;
    foreach ($array2 as $key2 => $arr2)
    {
        if ($arr1['ID'] === $arr2['ID'])
        {
            $amount += $arr2['Amount'];
            unset($array2[$key2]);
        }
    }

    $finalArray[] = array_merge($arr1, array(
        'Amount'    => $amount,
        'Found'     => $amount ? "Yes" : "No"
    ));
}

print_r($finalArray);
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 101
            [Code] => 1075
            [Date] => 2012-03-03 17:13:12.433
            [amount] => 6890
            [found] => Yes
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 103
            [Code] => 175
            [Date] => 2012-09-05 20:30:02.217
            [amount] => 1342
            [found] => Yes
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 109
            [Code] => 178
            [Date] => 2012-07-05 20:30:02.217
            [amount] => 0
            [found] => No
        )

)
```

Let me know if you need any further explanation.

Comment: please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56849413/function-to-simulate-left-join-on-array-not-working-properly-in-php)