# sort multidimensional array in alphabetical order of the keys in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, alphabetical-sort

I have an array like this with alphabetical keys :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [UserID] => 1
            [EmailAddress] => user5@gmail.com
            [TransID] => fjhf8f7848
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [UserID] => 1
            [EmailAddress] => johndoe@gmail.com
            [TransID] => dfsdhsdu78
        )

)
```

I want to sort this array in alphabetical order of the keys.
Expected output is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [EmailAddress] => user5@gmail.com
            [TransID] => fjhf8f7848
            [UserID] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [EmailAddress] => johndoe@gmail.com
            [TransID] => dfsdhsdu78
            [UserID] => 2
        )

)
```

I tried various array sort functions but they return blank.

How do I sort such a array with alphabetical keys in alphabetic order?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array_map and ksort,

```
$result = array_map(function(&$item){
    ksort($item); // sort by key
    return $item;
}, $arr);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/WResJ).

Using foreach loop,

```
foreach($arr as &$item){
    ksort($item);
}
```

**EDIT**
In that case you can use,

```
foreach($arr as &$item){
    uksort($item, function ($a, $b) {
      $a = strtolower($a); // making cases linient and then compare
      $b = strtolower($b);
      return strcmp($a, $b); // then compare
    });
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Pl6SD)

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [EmailAddress] => user5@gmail.com
            [TransID] => fjhf8f7848
            [UserID] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [EmailAddress] => johndoe@gmail.com
            [TransID] => dfsdhsdu78
            [UserID] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: this works. but if I have a key in lowercase let's say email then this key is pushed to the end after UserID. Rather it should be displayed before or after EmailAddress key

Comment: but you wanted to sort alphabetically right? email should logically comes at top.

Comment: in your code Email (uppercase E) is coming to the top but email (lowercase e) is going to the bottom.

Comment: if I have two keys starting with the same alphabet then they should come one after other rather than lowercase keys going to the end

Comment: You should research BEFORE posting a question here.  There are millions of pages, compiled for over a decade.  You are not the first person to undertake this kind of task.

Comment: @node_man please check my edit portion.